# Runtime error 'Object(...) is not a function' when consuming component package leveraging emotion/react

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I've got a component library that has introduced @emotion/react@v11.x. I am now trying to upgrade my ui project to use that new package, but I am getting a runtime error that appears to be related to how emotion is consuming react.

```
emotion-element-4fbd89c5.browser.esm.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (emotion-element-4fbd89c5.browser.esm.js:28)
    at Object.../node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-4fbd89c5.browser.esm.js (index.js:944)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:753)
    at fn (index.js:122)
    at Object.eval (emotion-react.browser.esm.js:10)
    at eval (emotion-react.browser.esm.js:362)
    at Object.../node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-react.browser.esm.js (index.js:956)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:753)
    at fn (index.js:122)
    (truncated)
```

Upon further inspection, the issue seems to be a problem with resolving the react 'createContext' function.

```
var EmotionCacheContext = /* #__PURE__ */Object(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["createContext"])( // we're doing this to avoid preconstruct's dead code elimination in this one case
```

The component library is using react v16.8.1 and the UI library is using the same version.

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and what worked for me was to delete my lockfile and node-modules then run `yarn` or `npm install`. After that I did an empty cache and hard reload in the browser. I also ran `gatsby clean` because I am using Gatsby. I'm not sure which step did the trick but this helped for me! Based off of your question, I'm guessing you are migrating to v1 of Chakra UI? If that's the case make sure you are following their migration docs [here](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/migration).