# Emotion - imported into project and getting errors TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, emotion

Similar to [Runtime error 'Object(...) is not a function' when consuming component package leveraging emotion/react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219146/runtime-error-object-is-not-a-function-when-consuming-component-package-l)

A library we use has started using Emotion, I've imported the latest but get this error when I try and run the component it's on

[image]

I've tried removing yarn.lock and node modules and it's not helping.

Answer (score 1):

According to this https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2103 it's an issue with React-Scripts